# Convert base 64 to pdf and display it as PDF. Not required to save the pdf in salesforce, Directly display

Tags: lightning, webservices, soap, salesforce-id, apex-webservice

When user clicks on a quick action, a soap webservice callout is made and in response we get base 64. I need to convert this base64 into PDF and display it online.
I dont want to save the pdf document anywhere. Directly display it as PDF.
Any help will be appreciated.

I referred code from below link but when I paste the base 64 i get from response of webservice it does not work and I get error that Failed to load the pdf document: Pasting the code here
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ax5sIAC

1) create a Visualforce page called HelloWorld:

```
<apex:page controller="DownloadPDF" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" contentType="application/pdf">
    <script>
        window.location.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,{!match1}"; // switch between match1,match2
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

2) create the controller DownloadPDF

```
public class DownloadPDF {
// Option 1: use an example PDF document base64 string 
    public String getMatch1() {
        string s = 'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
  'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
  'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
  'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
  'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
  'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
  'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
  'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
  'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
  'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
  'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
  'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
  'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G';
        return EncodingUtil.base64Decode(s).toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same requirement recently. You can just use `<object>` tag with `data` argument that contains your Base64 string:

```
<apex:page id="PDFPage" controller="YourController" showHeader="false" sideBar="false">
    <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,{!base64String}"></object>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can we achieve the same thing with the help of lightning component?

Comment: @user42184 I just embedded this VF page into a Lightning component with an iframe: `<iframe src="{! '/apex/PDFPage?recordId=' + v.recordId}" width="100%" height="700px" frameBorder="0"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Simple Lightning Component](https://github.com/kumarrk21/PDFViewer/tree/master) by KK Ramamoorthy to render the PDF from Base64 String inside Lightning Experience. This component uses the PDF.JS library and is very simple to use. You can either deploy the package directly or create the `pdfViewer` component manually.

Here is an example on how to use this `pdfViewer` component inside another Lightning Component.

*pdfViewerExampleComponent.cmp*

```
<aura:component implements  = "flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="pdfContainer" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button label="Popup" onclick="{!c.showPDFInPopup}"/>
    <lightning:button label="Inline" onclick="{!c.showInlinePDF}"/>
    {!v.pdfContainer}    
</aura:component>
```

*pdfViewerExampleComponentController.js*

```
({
    showPDFInPopup : function(component, pdfData) {
        var pdfData = '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';               
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:pdfViewer",
            {
                "pdfData": pdfData
            },
            function(pdfViewer, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                        cssClass: "slds-modal_medium",
                        header: "PDF Viewer",
                        body: pdfViewer, 
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        closeCallback: function() {
                        }
                    })                    
                } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );      
    },
    showInlinePDF : function(component, pdfData) {
        var pdfData = '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';               
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:pdfViewer",
            {
                "pdfData": pdfData
            },
            function(pdfViewer, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var pdfContainer = component.get("v.pdfContainer");
                    pdfContainer.push(pdfViewer);
                    component.set("v.pdfContainer", pdfContainer);                    
                } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );      
    },    
})
```

*Screen Grab:*
[image]

Comment: Saroj I tried your approach and installed the package but I am getting below error. I have removed the hardcoded base64 and referred the method from my controller as below. Error received on testing:                         
 Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': function(o,n){const i="modal",e="panel";function t(o){const n=parseInt(o,10);return isNaN(n)?0:n}class s{constr...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.

Also getting below error
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
 [Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]]

Comment: How you are calling these (`showPDFInPopup` or  'showInlinePDF') methods? You have to call these methods inside the `action.setCallback` from your action method (where you are getting the PDF String) by passing the PDF string as a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If we have to display the PDF from Base64 in the Visualforce page(VF Page) then here's the link that can help. Its working sweet and smooth.

https://sunilkhuwal.wordpress.com/2022/11/18/how-to-display-pdf-from-base64-data-in-salesforce-vf-page/